# Windows Form App Handles Error

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have a windows form application that has two main panels: The one on the left is a narrow strip which has a series of radio buttons. The panel on the right houses a Tabcontrol, which has multiple Tabpages added to it which the user can select among along the top. Each of these tabpages themselves has about 7 DataGridViews added to it. Each DataGridView has about 5-6 columns of text, with a variable number of rows (10-500). The data added to it was done directly to the DGV itself, ie using the DGV.Rows.Add() method, passing an object array, not via a datasource.

When a user selects a different tab page, the datagridview that gets shown is dependent on the radiobutton that is selected on the left. I accomplish this by handling the **SelectedIndexChange** event of the tabcontrol and each of the radiobutton's **CheckedChange** event.

Within the SelectedIndexChange event of the tabcontrol, I programmatically checked the currently selected radioButton. Then within the radiobutton's CheckedChange event, I iterate through all of the DataGridViews on the TabControl's **selectedTab** and hide all those that don't match the one corresponding to the selected radiobutton.

My issue is everytime the user starts changing among a lot of tabs, or tries to view a DGV that has many rows, the program would throw the following error:

**System.ComponentModel.Win32Exxception: Error creating window handle.**

Does anyone know what would cause the above error? My initial suspicion was that when I change to a different tabpage, the DGV on the original tabpage i was on was still in memory, but when I try calling .Dispose() on it, the DGV just disappears. It may be I am missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are probably trying to show a disposed `DataGridView`.

Do not dispose any `Control` in your form unless you are previously removing it from the appropiate `Container.Controls` collection (because you do not need it anymore and/or you plan adding a new one in its place). Otherwise dispose any controls when closing and disposing the `Form` that contains them if necessary.

In order to show the proper `DataGridView` depending on selected tab and user options use the `Visible` property or dynamically add and remove the needed controls to the container's `Controls` collection (in this case `TabPage.Controls`.

If its not that then maybe you have a "control leak" (probably event handler holding the object) and you are exceeding the windows handle limit for any given application (10.000 I think it is).

Comment: I am actually not calling .Dispose() on any form explicitly so if it is being done, it is being done automatically by the CLR. I was originally thinking I needed to do this because this error seems to crop up more often when there is a lot of information on the DGV, or when the user has had a long session open where he has changed the views many times.

Comment: @csharp_learner: I was adding info to the answer when you posted the comment. Read last paragraph and check the following related question:  [Winforms issue - Error creating window handle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222649/winforms-issue-error-creating-window-handle)

Comment: Hi InBetweeen, 
Regarding your third paragraph, I basically call .Hide() on the DGV's which are not supposed to be shown, which is equivalent to setting the .Visible = true/false.

I have taken a look at the task manager and noticed the following behavior when i started switching between tabpages:

The "Handles" column stayed below 400 at all times. The "USER Objects" column however jumped about 40 each time i switched to a different tabpage. When it hits 300, i start getting the dreaded error above. GDI object count also goes up by 1.

Let me know if the above information can assist. Thanks.