# "Error creating window handle"

Tags: c#, winforms, window, handle

I'm getting this nasty 'error creating window handle' during the startup itself i.e the login form. I would have looked into the optimizing the controls if it would have come after the UI is up. This is coming during the load of first form which basically has only login & password textbox controls.

The program is C# winforms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms issue - Error creating window handle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222649/winforms-issue-error-creating-window-handle)

Answer (score 0):

I probably need more information but my guess is that you have a memory leak somewhere in your program. Try running Task Manager to see if you have a thread or handle growing massive.

If you do, you probably need to dispose some UI elements somewhere in your code.